# hibernate multiple schema database EmptyInterceptor

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, interceptor

how can i use interceptor hibernate to connect to multiple database dynamically?

i already do something like that

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName="prototypeUnit")
 protected transient EntityManager entityManager;

 @PersistenceContext(unitName="prototypeErdf")
 protected transient EntityManager entityManagerErdf;
```

I can with that connect to différent database but it's not dynamic, my technical Manager tell me that i must use inteceptor hibernate, how can i do that?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate 4 Multi-tenancy feature to connect to Different databases dynamically.

Refer to the documentation:-
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4745